# VB.NET for each loop not working

Tags: vb.net, foreach

I have a listbox that has x amount of object loaded from a txt file with this code:

```
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath() + "\file.txt")
    List.Items.AddRange(lines)

    Try
        List.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

    Return True
```

It loads them fine. Then I only try to loop through them like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim num As Integer = 0
    Dim item As Object

    For Each item In List.Items
        List.SelectedIndex = num
        num += 1
    Next

End Sub
```

The error I get is this:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified. An enumerator can only be used if the list does not change.

I tried to load the listbox manually, didn't help.
Any help here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that loop?

Comment: Only to change the selected index. @Fairy

Comment: Never use an empty try-catch.  It hides problems.

Comment: But why loop it? Whats the point? Do you want to go trough every item and select it?

Comment: Yes. The point is to go through each item. Later I can then add something with it @Fairy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
    For num = 0 To List.Items.Count - 1
        List.SelectedIndex = num
    Next
```

And as @CodyGray rightly pointed out: The reason for this is A for-each loop cannot be used if you're going to modify the collection of items you're enumerating over.

This will end up with the last item selected so it's only really of any use if you're testing out your event handlers for every item.

Comment: You should explain *why* you have to do this. In other words, *why* your solution fixes the problem. (A for-each loop cannot be used if you're going to modify the collection of items you're enumerating over.)